# Fastest way to remove all items from dropdown list or listbox?

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list with more than one thousand items. Once I click on `clear` button it should clear all items. For removing I tried looping.

What would be the fastest way to remove all items from a dropdown list or listbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set innerHTML of select box as empty string.

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectboxID");
selectBox.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

An option if you're using jQuery:

```
$("#selectboxID").empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick reply How about this?? 
document.getElementById(id).options.length = 0;